# Variable from html to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-applications

I am wondering on how to solve my problem , but I don't know which is the best way to do this. 
So I have an **html** page in which I am passing a `id` through `$_GET[id_plot])` that I print it like this :

```
  echo "var id_get_plot = '".$_GET[id_plot]."'; ";
```

That , I suppose is a global variable , that , let's say it clearly, we all hate. 
The goal is to use this `var` inside an external `script`.

The solution I am adopting right now is to instanciate a `namespace` and then binding the `var` to it , like this :

**HTML**

```
      echo " Model = Model || {};
             Model.id_get_plot = '".$_GET[id_plot]."'; ";
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
      Model = Model || {};
      Model.get_id = function(){ 
         console.log(this.id_get_plot) //it prints the right value
      });
```

What I am thinking is : is this a good way to solve my problem? There are other , and if possible, more elegant way to solve this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: _"...elegant way to solve this?"_, yup, AJAX is the elegant way.

Comment: Don't generate JavaScript from PHP. Use `json_encode()` to create a JSON object that your JS can use. This decouples the two languages, and your data will be properly escaped

Comment: @elclanrs Normally I'd agree - AJAX is a good solution, but it's a bit heavyweight just to pass a small amount of fixed data into a page. json_encode() is quick and easy.

Comment: @elclanrs Making an extra request when it's not needed? Not that elegant

Comment: Ok, I got it , but I was also wondering on how "pass" the id from the html to the javascript. Is namespace a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't generate JavaScript from PHP. Use json_encode() to create a JSON object that your JS can use. This decouples the two languages, and your data will be properly escaped

The simplest thing to put it into a namespace is the following, there are better ways, but this should get you going.

```
var Model = window.Model || {
     getId: function() {
        return this.id;
     },
     // Would be better as a constructor, but since you want a singleton
     init: function(id) {
         this.id = id;
     }
};
// If you need more than one value, make an object out of this....
Model.init(<?php echo json_encode($_GET['id_plot']) ?>)
```

Comment: This is really new to me. I did not know that i could use php inside javascript. thank you!

Comment: Uhm..it is not getting the value from the GET call \:

Comment: @steo Yes there was a typo in there, it's fixed, but you should have been able to find it because the syntactically incorrect